# I accidentally created a Google calendar event in the year 15 AD, and now I can't delete it.

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

The app I'm working on creates events in a Google calendar. Due to <strike>time travel</strike> a DateTime bug, my event was created in 15 AD. The Google calendar web interface seems unable to cope with this, and even upon finding my event (using the search bar), there's no way to delete it. I checked the js console, and it appears that something has evaluated to null on their site.

```
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.La')
    Nf (undefined, line 168)
    XO
    (anonymous function) ([native code], line 0)
    C
    (anonymous function) ([native code], line 0)
    f
    Bh (dc315ccd9d63034627cb97eaba422ebdcalendarjs_doozercompiled__en.js, line 113)
    sba (dc315ccd9d63034627cb97eaba422ebdcalendarjs_doozercompiled__en.js, line 114)
    (anonymous function) (dc315ccd9d63034627cb97eaba422ebdcalendarjs_doozercompiled__en.js, line 111)
```

I can't believe Google doesn't support editing events created 2000 years in the past. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find and delete the event programatically (using the API/interface you used to create it) instead of using the web GUI - it *might* use a different codepath which *might* be unaffected by the issue you describe.